# AngularJS/JavaScript object overriding property in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have a strange problem in JavaScript. I have a variable that I need to be accessible because I'll be using that Object in many occurences. I'm trying to add dynamic properties in a new variable, but for whatever reason, that global Object is not having the same state as the beginning.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    var aOptions = {
        'apple': {
            source: { type: 'tree' },
            color: 'white'
        }
    };

    function addParams(params, option) {
        params.source.property = option;
        return params;
    }
    $scope.todos = addParams(aOptions.apple, 'new_option');
    $scope.todos1 = addParams(aOptions.apple, 'new_option2');
}
```

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tzam0ed6/

My `$scope.todos` needs to have `"new_option"` new value and `$scope.todos1` needs to have the new `"new_option2"` value but for some weird reason, it overrides the current object.

---

See @TeoMor's answer.

Comment: If you want to copy an object, you must make a copy.

Comment: As @SLaks suggested, use [`angular.copy`](http://jsfiddle.net/vghb45bo/)

Comment: you call twice `addParamas` with `aOptions.apple` as first argument, so the second call will override the `aOptions.apple.source.property`. I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzam0ed6/1/

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. It was about reference vs. copy and all I needed to do is angular.copy() in my addParams function and it's done.